# What does the author mean by "Platform Layer"

Tags: architecture

I was reading this article "http://lethain.com/introduction-to-architecting-systems-for-scale/". In the end, the authors mentions platform layer. I don't understand the scope of this layer and its advantages. Could you please clarify?

thanks

Answer (score 7):

There are 3 benefits of this layer listed after the diagram.

I can give an example to help. Say you have a web site that serves some pages and does some very heavy calculations for some requests.

If both of these functions were on the web server, then a calculation could slow the response time of the web pages. Having it on a seperate server avoids this problem.

In our architecture drawings we call this layer the application server or business layer rather than the platform layer. We call Azure or the .net framework a platform.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much the platform layer is where your business logic resides.
Imagine you have a site for selling cookies.

1. You have a web server running apache/iis that handles http requests
2. You have an application server ( windows/linux/etc. ) that exposes a custom API for handling sales, reports etc - you call a method via http get or some web service to get the report for sales ... etc ... etc ...
3. And finally you have a Database server which handles ... data storage.

Imagine your site grows to the size of amazon.com, then adding new web servers, app servers (platform layer) and db servers get easier.

Scalling out it is called.

Comment: Isn't it then becomes as following:
1. Load balancer
2. Web server (in other words Application server)
3. Database server ?

Comment: @candle It would be something like 1. Load balancer (distributes requests across web servers), 2. Web server (knows what apis to call according to the incoming request), 3. Load balancer (distributes requests across application layer servers), 4. Application layer (exposes business logic through apis)